# Do the tiles in Bounce 'n' Trounce fall in a random order?

Tags: mario-party-superstars

In the minigame Bounce 'n' Trounce, do the floor tiles fall away in a random order? Or is there a predetermined order every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When 20 seconds remain on the timer, the 8 outside tiles will begin falling in a random order. One tile will fall every two seconds. The tile in the center will always remain at the end.

I determined this by comparing videos of the Bounce n' Trounce minigame, ([video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmMy3-ZZ0PY), [video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqcjRrY8a1I), [video 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IW2s2fiAdXk)), and noting what order the tiles fell.